# SageOne API Sandbox Account?

Tags: api, sandbox, account, demo

I've been asked to look into developing an application to use the SageOne API which on the face of it seems quite straight forward. The only issue is, as a developer I don't have a SageOne account as such, so was wondering what people do here in this situation as information seems to be scares on the SageOne Site.

I've registered my development application with my GitHub account and added all the keys to the code (using .NET) when the application calls for authorization it asks me to sign in which I would expect, I've created a trial accountant account to test but (obviously) this is empty.

So any one know of any sandbox accounts and if so how to go about getting some test data inside the account so I can test my API?

Many thanks in advance.
Mike

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got set up, and emailed them to get my 30-day free trial converted to to a 1 year developer account.

So it is possible to get a developer account. Though they don't seem to be properly set up for developers yet. They need an easy way to set up sandbox accounts, and the sandbox accounts need to be permanent. The obvious reason being that I'll still need a sandbox account for testing, even after the development is finished.

They do know that they're not developer friendly right now and are looking into ways to make the developer path a lot more smooth.

Once you're set up, make sure you email them with your comments, and sign up for their (rather old and primitive), developer forum.

Like a lot of companies that started out with desktop products, they're finding their way in the new cloud hosted web world.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have an answer to my own question, essentially they don't have demo accounts so looks like I will have to run a new trial every 30 days and load it with some imported CSV's each time.

Comment: How did you register? Where did you get the keys from? I've signed up but can't see anywhere to get the keys I need to add to my app so I can register it.

Comment: Hi, I went to [link](https://developers.sageone.com) and in the drop down box select my application. You can register from there. Hope that helps.